# How to using join table in SORM?

Tags: scala, join, sorm

I fond Join defined in package sorm.sql ,but I don't know how to use .
I don't found join table using method, from SORM source .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SORM's API abstracts from all relational concepts. Joins are performed by SORM internally, whenever it considers them required.

Comment: sorry , I have this problem.  
  case class Person(name:String)   
  case class Order(title:String,price:Double)   
  case class PersonOrder(person:Person,order:Order)   
  case class Department(name:String)   
  case class PersonDepartment(person:Person,deparment:Department)   

  I want get order list for person ,using DepartmentID.   


  How to using SORM do this ?   

  Simular multi level entitits cascade,what can I do ?

Comment: See the following answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13629324/485115, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13863337/485115

Comment: val orders = db.query[PersonOrder].whereIn("person",
      db.query[PersonDepartment]
        .whereEqual("department.name", "Basic Process Unit")
        .fetch().map(_.person)
    ).fetch().map(_.order)       I can using this query get I want.Thank you , Nikita Volkov~.